# Recursive Polynomial Problem

Tags: polynomials

Source: Purple Comet Competition 2017 High School Question 12

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial satisfying $P(x+1) + P(x-1) = x^3$ for all real numbers $x$. Find the value of $P(12)$.

I am pretty sure one is supposed to write down several "formulas", and then cancel everything out to leave $P(12)$ behind, but I cannot get the answer and would like some help in solving this problem. What is the correct and easiest way to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\;P(0)=0$ since the RHS <s>has no free term</s> is odd. Then, using $P(x+1)=x^3-P(x-1)\,$:

$$
P(12)=11^3 - P(10) = 11^3-9^3+ P(8)= \cdots=11^3-9^3+7^3-5^3+3^3-1^3+P(0)
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  As pointed out in a comment, why $\,P(0)=0\,$ needs some additional elaboration.

Main point is that the RHS of the given identity is an odd function. Writing the equalities for $\,x\,$ and $\,-x\,$, then adding up together, gives:

$$
P(x+1)+P(x-1)+P(-x+1)+P(-x-1) = x^3 + (-x)^3=0
$$

With $\,Q(x)=P(x)+P(-x)\,$ the above can be rewritten as:

$$
Q(x+1)+Q(x-1) = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; Q(x+2)+Q(x)=0
$$

That implies that for each root $\,a\,$ of $\,Q(x)\,$, $a+2$ is also a root. Since a non-zero polynomial cannot have infinitely many roots, it follows that $\,Q(x) \equiv 0\,$. This in turn implies that $\,P(x)+P(-x) \equiv 0\,$ and substituting $\,x=0\,$ gives $\,P(0)=0\,$.

Comment: can you please explain how you got P(0) = 0? Also, what is RHS?

Comment: @PrashanthMohan RHS is *right-hand side*, whatever comes to the right of the `=` equal sign, in this case $\,x^3\,$. As for $\,P(0)\,$ that's the free (or constant) term of $\,P(x)\,$. I'll edit the answer to clarify that part.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly the polynomial is cubic, and coefficient of $x^3$ is $1/2$.

So $p(x)=(1/2)x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

Now we have $P(2)=1-c$ and $P(-2)=-1-c$

so $4+4a+2b=1-c$ and

$-4+4a-2b=-1-c$

Adding the two eqn's we have $a=-c/4$ and $b=-3/2$.
Now the constant term of $P(x+1)+P(x-1)$ is $1/2+a+b+c-1/2+a-b+c=2a+2c=0$

So, $a=-c$, hence $a=c=0$

So our polynomial is $(x^3-3x)/2$.

So $p(12)=846$.

Comment: sorry i corrected it

Comment: I did not get how you acquired the information in the first sentence. Can you please explain it in further detail?

Comment: ya made a mistake, $P(0)=0$ requires a proper explanation

Comment: Can you explain how the coefficient is 0.5? That is the only thing I don't get.

Comment: Say the coefficient of $x^3$ in $P(x)$ is $d$. Then what is the coeffcient of $x^3$ in $P(x+1)$, it's also $d$...Think...! In this way we get $2d=1$!